# Audio is playing without visualization

Tags: javascript, audio

I am trying to play audio without any visualisation. I have used the code below :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div#mp3_player{ width:500px; height:120px; background:#000; padding:5px; margin:50px auto; border-radius: 10px; }
        div#mp3_player > div > audio{  width:500px; background:#000; float:left;   }
        div#mp3_player > canvas{ width:500px; height:60px; padding: 0px; background:#ffffff; float:left; border-radius: 10px;}
    </style>
    <script>
        window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
        // Create a new instance of an audio object and adjust some of its properties
        var audio = new Audio();
        audio.src = 'UncleFlexxx - Camry 3.5.mp3';
        audio.controls = true;
        audio.loop = true;
        audio.autoplay = true;
        // Establish all variables that your Analyser will use
        var canvas, ctx, source, context, analyser, fbc_array, bars, bar_x, bar_width, bar_height;
        // Initialize the MP3 player after the page loads all of its HTML into the window
        window.addEventListener("load", initMp3Player, false);
        function initMp3Player(){
            document.getElementById('audio_box').appendChild(audio);
            context = new webkitAudioContext(); // AudioContext object instance
            analyser = context.createAnalyser(); // AnalyserNode method
            canvas = document.getElementById('analyser_render');
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            // Re-route audio playback into the processing graph of the AudioContext
            source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
            source.connect(analyser);
            analyser.connect(context.destination);
            frameLooper();
        }
        // frameLooper() animates any style of graphics you wish to the audio frequency
        // Looping at the default frame rate that the browser provides(approx. 60 FPS)
        function frameLooper(){
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(frameLooper);
            fbc_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
            analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array);
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Clear the canvas
            ctx.fillStyle = 'white'; // Color of the bars
            bars = 100;
            for (var i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
                bar_x = i * 3;
                bar_width = 4;
                bar_height = -(fbc_array[i] / 2.5);
                //  fillRect( x, y, width, height ) // Explanation of the parameters below
                ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mp3_player">
    <div id="audio_box"></div>
    <canvas id="analyser_render"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I do not know what to do! I've tried injecting `window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;` but nothing has changed! I have no familiar programmers, so I came here, please help. Looks like google can't read this code or what I don't know.

Google considers `context = new webkitAudioContext();` as an error !

Comment: I think you just need to add the audio tag somewhere in the DOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the audio tag into the dom

```
    var audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = 'UncleFlexxx - Camry 3.5.mp3';
    audio.controls = true;
    audio.loop = true;
    audio.autoplay = true;
    document.getElementById("mp3_player").appendChild(audio);
```

Comment: Give me pastebin.com please

Comment: @FerFooy It's just 1 line of code. Pastebin is overkill

Comment: @FerFooy I'm confused. You say _"I am trying to play audio **without** any visualisation"_ then you show code you tried which is **with** visual. Now it seems like you're just asking how to remove the visual part. You get Answer for that but then you now say _"visualization doesn’t work"_ ...**(1)** Do you want the visualization to happen when audio plays? Yes or no? **(2)** This is marked as correct. Is your problem solved or you need visuals?